# Android SurfaceTexture save previous texture for later use

Tags: android, camera, opengl-es, surfaceview

I am using surfaceTexture class on Android to get frame from camera.
The surfaceTexture expects an opengl "GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES" texture at creation and each time a new frame is available the callback registered with
setOnFrameAvailableListener is called, then updateTexImage overwrite the previous frame with the current frame on the oesTexture.
Is there a way to keep the previous texture ? I would like to keep a few for analysis (and keep them as external textures).

I have seen the SurfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext() function, but it internally calls glDeleteTextures(oesTextureId), so I don't understand the purpose of this function.

```
public class SurfaceTextureWrapper
{
    public static int generateTexture(int target) {
        final int textureArray[] = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureArray, 0);
        final int textureId = textureArray[0];
        GLES20.glBindTexture(target, textureId);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(target, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(target, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(target, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(target, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        return textureId;
    }

    public SurfaceTextureWrapper() 
    {
        this.oesTextureId = generateTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
        this.surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(this.oesTextureId);
        this.surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener((st) -> {
            surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            //how to save the texture called oesTextureId for later use ?
            //as another call to updateTexImage will replace it with a new frame
        }, handler);
    }

}
```